# The intuition behind generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

An ordinary eigenvector can be viewed as a vector on which the operator acts by only stretching (without rotating) it.

Is there a similar intuition behind generalized eigenvectors?

EDIT: By generalized eigenvectors I'm referring to vectors in the kernel of $(T-\lambda I)^k$ for some $k$.

Comment: @Irene: Do you want only the geometric explanation

Comment: If you don't mind clarifying, you're referring to the generalized eigenproblem $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}$, yes?

Comment: @J.M.: I think she is refering to the vectors that show up in, e.g., the Jordan Canonical form: vectors in $\mathbf{N}((T-\lambda I)^n)$ for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: Arturo: Oh okay, I got confused because I work with eigenvalues/eigenvectors of matrix pencils (which is also called the generalized eigenproblem in numerical linear algebra books).

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining clearly - I meant what Arturo said.

Comment: @Chandru1: Not necessarily, though a geometrical explanation could be a nice start.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some intuition is afforded by the Jordan Normal Form, and even more is obtained by understanding a proof.

The Jordan form of an endomorphism decomposes it as the direct sum of "Jordan blocks"; if you have an intuition for what a block is doing, you can understand the entire direct sum.

A Jordan block geometrically is the sum of two operations.  One rescales everything by a constant, the eigenvalue.  The other essentially collapses the module onto a codimension one submodule.

The collapsing is the nilpotent part.  A geometric intuition is obtained by considering the simplest nontrivial example, the linear map defined (in coordinates) by $(x,y) \to (y,0)$: two dimensions are collapsed onto one essentially by forgetting the first dimension.

In a Jordan block, the nilpotent operation is generally $(x,y, \ldots, z) \to (y, \ldots, z, 0)$.  This establishes a hierarchy in the module: the last dimension generates the kernel of $T$, the last two dimensions are killed by $T^2$, and so on.  Iterating $T$ enough times eventually produces the zero map--that's what it means to be nilpotent.  Thus the kernel of $(T-\lambda I)^k$ picks up all the Jordan blocks associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and, speaking somewhat loosely, each generalized eigenvector gets rescaled by $\lambda$, *up to some "error" term* generated by certain of the other generalized eigenvectors.

In two dimensions, then, a Jordan block effects a transformation that can be written in suitable coordinates (given by two of the generalized eigenvectors) as $(x,y) \to (\lambda x + y, \lambda y)$: an isothety and skew transformation together.  The geometric picture isn't really any different for higher-dimensional blocks.

Answer (score 20):

Consider first eigenvectors associated to $0$; these are elements of the nullspace. Now, it is possible for a vector to not lie in the nullspace, but for its image to lie in the nullspace (for example, consider the linear transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T(x,y) = (y,0)$; then $T(0,1) = (1,0)$, and $T(T(0,1))=(0,0)$. Or for the image of the image to lie in the nullspace... etc. If you want to think about all the vectors that will *eventually* map to zero if you keep applying $T$ (which seems like a sensible thing to think about in many circumstances), then you are looking for the vectors that lie in union of the nullspaces of $T^n$, $n=1,2,\ldots$. Notice that $\mathbf{N}(T^n)\subseteq\mathbf{N}(T^{n+1})$, so this is an increasing union. Once a vector maps to $0$ under a power of $T$, it stays there. These vectors are *precisely* the generalized eigenvectors of $T$ associated to $\lambda=0$.

So, what about arbitrary eigenvalues? Instead of thinking of an eigenvector associated to $\lambda$ as a vector on which $T$ acts by stretching/compressing, think of an eigenvector associated to $\lambda$ as an element of the nullspace of $T-\lambda I$. The generalized eigenvector associated to $\lambda$ are then the vectors that lie in $\mathbf{N}((T-\lambda I)^n)$ for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: Are you using $\mathbf{N}$ to denote the kernel of the operator?

Comment: Yes; in linear algebra it is often called "nullspace"; it is very prevalent notation (e.g., Friedberg, Insel, and Spence use it).

Comment: I don't believe I've seen this notation before. Maybe only once or twice in the first course in linear algebra. I'll keep that in mind, though!

Comment: @AsafKaragila This notation is relatively common in functional analysis books, together with $\mathrm{R}(T)=\mathrm{Im}(T)$ for the range of $T$.

Comment: @Olivier: That comment was made three years ago!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh ... sorry about that : ) this question must have received a new answer, or have been bumped up by the site for it landed on my front page! I never noticed this was so old ^^

Comment: @Olivier: No, it has received an edit. Although the edit was to the newest answer which is itself nearly a year older than the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, then it's only fitting a three year old comment should receive a reply today!

Comment: But why one would be interested in finding kernel of $T,T^2,\dots$? or $(T-\lambda I),(T-\lambda I)^2,\dots$

Answer (score 2):

Generalized eigenvectors also have an interpretation in system dynamics:
If only generalized eigenvectors can be found the dynamics components (=blocks in Jordan canonical form) *cannot* be completely decoupled. Only if the respective matrix is fully diagonizable a full decoupling is possible.

See also this instructive video from Stanford university (from about 1:00 hours on):
http://academicearth.org/courses/introduction-to-linear-dynamical-systems

Comment: This is not an interpretation of generalised eigenvectors, just of eigenvectors -- and analogous "interpretations" exist in pretty much any field where linear algebra is used.