# What is the geometric intuition behind algebraic multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the number of times $\lambda$ appears as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is dimension of the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Let us consider the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ for simplicity. Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has the eigenvalue $\lambda$ as a repeated root, $2$ times. For example, if the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ were a line (one-dimensional), we could visualize $T$ as the transformation squishing or stretching all vectors on that line by an amount $\lambda$. But what is the geometric significance of the algebraic multiplicity $2$, in this case? Is there any underlying **geometric** intuition?

Comment: @Lucas That's not necessarily true.

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity is the dimension of the generalized eigenspace, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: The set of all eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a vector -supspace $S$  on which the transformation is a dilation  of magnitude  $\lambda$  centered at the origin if $\lambda>0, $ or a dilation  centered at the origin of magnitude $|\lambda|$ followed by (or preceded by) a reflection in the origin if $\lambda<0, $ or the transformattion maps $S$ to $\{0\}$ if $\lambda=0.$  Moreover $S$ is the largest such vector-subspace.

Comment: @ChrisRandall Could you please elaborate that in an answer?

Comment: @Blue you might find my discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/472958/81360) to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the dimension of its eigenspace. The algebraic multiplicity is the dimension of what's called the generalized eigenspace.

If you have a linear transformation, represented by a matrix A, and an eigenvalue $\lambda$, a generalized eigenvector is a vector, $v$ such that for some integer n, $$(A-\lambda I)^nv =0$$

Then, the space formed by taking all such generalized eigenvectors is called the generalized eigenspace and its dimension is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$.

There's a nice discussion of the intuition behind generalized eigenvectors [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/the-intuition-behind-generalized-eigenvectors).